# Trouble with pyinstaller(compiling an executable)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to turn my script into an exe file but it doesn't work this is the code that happens. All it says at the end is tuple index out of range and I don't know what that is or what it means. Here is the full log that happens when I try to turn it into an executable.

```
 C:\Users\Smith 1>pyinstaller Calculator.py
    73 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
    73 INFO: Python: 3.6.0
    73 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
    75 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Smith 1\Calculator.spec
    75 INFO: UPX is not available.
    79 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
    ['C:\\Users\\Smith 1', 'C:\\Users\\Smith 1']
    80 INFO: checking Analysis
    81 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
    81 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
    88 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
    89 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 317, in assemble
    excludes=self.excludes, user_hook_dirs=self.hookspath)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 560, in initialize_modgraph
    graph.import_hook(m)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1509, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1661, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 209, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2077, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2115, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2951, in _load_package
    self._load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2167, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2585, in _scan_code
    module, module_code_object, is_scanning_imports=False)
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2831, in _scan_bytecode
    global_attr_name = get_operation_arg_name()
  File "c:\users\smith 1\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2731, in get_operation_arg_name
    return module_code_object.co_names[co_names_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6.0 isn't supported by Pyisntaller.

Comment: This is outdated information. Now it does support Python 3.6+: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/2266

Comment: As of 17 July, 2017, that issue is still open.  Reading around on the Pyinstaller repo, it looks like 3.6 compatibility is close, but not yet official.  So it might be possible to get the current development version of Pyinstaller to work.